# Python: selecting rows by hour in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime, dataframe

**I have the below dataframe in csv file, I would like to select all rows corresponding to current hour.**

```
time,values

2018-10-28 08:16:49.469508,48

2018-10-28 08:16:54.471987,48

2018-10-28 08:16:59.475236,48

2018-10-28 08:17:04.478681,48
```

**Below is the funtion I am trying**
    current = datetime.datetime.now()

```
start = datetime.datetime(current.year,current.month,current.day,current.hour,0)

end = datetime.datetime(current.year,current.month,current.day,current.hour,59)

df = pd.io.parsers.read_csv('water_data1.csv', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)

print(df.query('start < time < end'))
```

**I get the following error**

> pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'start' is not defined

**Could someone suggest what is the right syntax to achieve this.
Thanks
Hemanth**

Comment: Using between :-)

Comment: print(df.query('@start < time < @end')) is the correct syntax for query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pd.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) requires external variables to be preceded by `@`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list(range(10))})

start, end = 3, 6

print(df.query('@start < A < @end'))

   A
4  4
5  5
```

You can also use [`pd.Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
res = df[df['A'].between(start, end, inclusive=False)]
```

Finally, when working with `datetime` values, you should prefer [`pd.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timestamp.html) over regular Python types:

```
now = pd.Timestamp('now')
start = now.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
end = now.replace(second=59, microsecond=0)

print((start, end))

(Timestamp('2018-11-01 17:36:00'), Timestamp('2018-11-01 17:36:59'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
df[(df['time'] > start) & (df['time'] < end])]
```